# Is a Gaussian multiplied with sigma $\mathcal{N}(0,1)\cdot\sigma_i^2$ the same as a Gaussian with sigma $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_i^2)$?

Tags: normal-distribution

I am a programmer and I have a 4-D matrix **`M`** and a 4-D matrix **`sigma`**. I want to corrupt each of **`M`**'s entries with Gaussian noise with an individual stddev per entry (stored in sigma **`sigma`**). Doing this brute-force (with loops) is not feasible due to performance limitations.

I have a tool to cheaply generate a 4-D matrix filled with values sampled of a normal distribution with mean `m = 0.0` and `stddev=1.0` ($\sigma$). I was wondering now: Can I use that to generate Gaussian noise and then do an (also cheap) element-wise multiplication with my 4-D **`sigma`**-Matrix to get an "individual" Gaussian for each element? In essence I think this boils down to:

**Is $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_i^2) = \mathcal{N}(0,1)\cdot\sigma_i^2$**

Or is there another operation that can transform a $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ to a $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_i^2)$?

Comment: In your (not very rigorous) notation, $N(0, \sigma_i^2) = N(0, 1) \cdot \sigma_i$.

Comment: $N(0,1)\cdot \sigma$ has stdev $\sigma$.

Comment: Cool, so just not squaring it does the job? That is excellent. Mind making it into an answer I can accept?

Comment: @Honeybear Exactly. But it is too short to be an answer. If it helped you, then it is good enough